enable log debug! macros/force log-level in one dependency
Is there a way to instruct cargo to compile a dependency (enigo) in a way I get log crate's debug! level for it? It deals with wayland connections which is hell, and it doesn't bubble up much error information.
Already tried initializing a logger implementation with debug level.   stderrlog::new().module(module_path!()).verbosity(3).quiet(false).init().unwrap(); but that is limited to my application.
Already tried to force "dev" profile on the dependency: enigo = { ..., profile = "dev", debug = 2 }. Does nothing.
Already tried to edit the downloaded dep's Cargo.toml to change log's compile time features, and change the log dependency to include debug logs on prod builds: features = ["max_level_debug", "release_max_level_debug"]. Then cargo clean on the deps (~/.Cargo/registry/src/...), then cargo build --offline on my project. Does nothing.
Is there a sane way to change log level on a dependency?

This would be dependent on the logger you've initialized and not the log facade. Looks like you just need to add .module("enigo") to your stderrlog setup.

@kmdreko thank you! I knew I was overlooking something obvious and much more ergonomic than what my mind was focusing on :) that was exactly it!

Couldn't find good docs for this but, as pointed out by @kmdreko comment, some loggers implement a way to override the module options. Most docs just mention that module property defaults to the current module path, if it is even mentioned...
 fn main() {
    stderrlog::new()
        .module(module_path!())
+       .module("enigo")
        .verbosity(3)
        .quiet(false)
        .init().unwrap();



The docs for this specific feature are here: https://docs.rs/stderrlog/latest/stderrlog/#module-level-logging
